# Angular 5 parent and child animations not working at the same time

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to create side menu with additional animation for inner arrow element:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-menu-animation

In this realization animations are working in the next order:

1. Menu is opening
2. Arrow is rotating

But I want to start this 2 animations at the same time. It works good in Angular 4.4.x but not working in 5.2.x.

Need some help with this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check my working fork [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-menu-animation-trhdqv).

You have to add the [group](https://angular.io/api/animations/group) function so that the steps are executed in parallel instead of in sequence as sequence is taken by default.

```
 import { group } from '@angular/animations';

 transition('in <=> out', [
    group([
      query('@buttonInOut', [
        animateChild()
      ]),
      animate('300ms ease-out')
    ])
  ])
```

If you check the docs on [sequence](https://angular.io/api/animations/sequence), it is said that;

> `sequence` Specifies a list of animation steps that are run one by
>   one. (sequence is used by default when an array is passed as animation
>   data into transition.)
>
> The sequence function can either be used within a group or a
>   transition and it will only continue to the next instruction once each
>   of the inner animation steps have completed.
>
> To perform animation styling in parallel with other animation steps
>   then have a look at the group animation function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nico. You save a lot of my time.